# How to get the value of a key value pair in python?

Tags: python, list

```
example = [{'name':'nikhil', 'class':10 , 'age':17 }]
print(example['name'])
```

I want to get the value of the key but here it throws error.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Square brackets should be included. So is it possible to get the key value pair in such a case?

Comment: `example[0]['name']` you have a dict inside a list, so you first have to select the dict with id 0 from the list

Comment: `arr = example[0]; arr.get("name")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets (`[]`) are a list. The curly brackets (`{}`) are a dictionary (key-value data structure).

You first need the access the element of the list (first element is at index `0`) containing the dictionary, which you can then access via a `key` (e.g. `'name'`).

```
example = [{'name': 'nikhil', 'class': 10 , 'age': 17 }]
print(example[0]['name'])
```

You can think of it in the following steps:

```
example = [{'name': 'nikhil', 'class': 10 , 'age': 17 }]
first_element = example[0]
value_of_name = first_element['name']
print(value_of_name)
```